# Ошибка при умножении в android

Tags: android

Мне нужно вычислить стоимость полученного времени, если есть цена за 1 сутки.
Делаю следующим образом:

```
        long hoursDays = diff/(60*60*1000);
        long priceHour = Long.valueOf(etPriceZas.getText().toString());

        long result1 = priceHour/24;
        long result = result1  * hoursDays;
```

Сначала получаю количество времени в часах, затем стоимость за сутки делю на 24 часа и полученные числа умножаю друг на друга.

Но вот беда в чем, если ввожу цену за сутки 1200 - то все правильно, а если 1000 - после всех вычислений выдает - 984 рубля за 24 часа.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы используете long.

Здесь

```
long result1 = priceHour/24;
```

в result1 будет только целая часть (1200/24 = ровно 50, а 1000/24 = целая часть 41, а вся дробная отбрасывается). Если я правильно понял, то вам вместо long просто надо использовать float.